# Additional Window After Only Creating 1 Window - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

## Main

I have the code like the following.

```
# Modules
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

# Functions
def information():
    pass
def main_page():
    pass

# Main Window
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("TButton", background="white", foreground="black", padding = 15, font=("Arial", 10))
root = Tk()
root.title("iHealthy")
root.iconbitmap("iHealthy.ico")
window_width = 500
window_height = 400
root.config(bg="white")
root.resizable(False, False)
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
center_x = int(screen_width / 2 - window_width / 2)
center_y = int(screen_height / 2 - window_height / 2)
root.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}")
root.configure()

# Script
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=2)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=2)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=2)
root.columnconfigure(3, weight=2)
information_page = ttk.Button(root, text="Take Tour", command=lambda: information())
home_page = ttk.Button(root, text="Home Page", command=lambda: main_page())
information_page.pack()
home_page.pack()

# Mainloop
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("TButton", background="white", foreground="black", padding = 15, font=("Arial", 10))
mainloop()
```

## Problem

The code looks just fine to me. But it has several problems. The problems are:

- The code opens an additional window running the code.
- The windows immediately shuts down and opens again.
- The program will sometimes blink.

> The third option is not always, I mean sometimes.

Comment: Please learn how to use Toplevel.

Comment: Try to create `ttk.Style()` after creating `Tk()`. Actually you can remove the two lines before creating `Tk()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `root.mainloop()` at the end of your file instead of just `mainloop()` since `root` is what is instantiating `Tk()`.

Realistically, this should also be wrapped in a guard clause like this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

but that's a separate issue.